# throw new CustomException vs. Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR

Tags: c#, exception, com

I have a question regarding Exceptions and returning control to a COM caller. Below is a test question with a custom exception class. What is the difference between

```
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(CustomException.COR_E_ARGUMENT);
```

and

```
throw new CustomException("Argument is out of bounds");
```

I kind of get why 1) and 2 doesn't work as they return an int and an Exception-object. But what's the difference between 3 and 4?

```
public class CustomException : ApplicationException
{
   public static int COR_E_ARGUMENT = unchecked((int)0x80070057);
   public CustomException(string msg)
      : base(msg)
   {
      HResult = COR_E_ARGUMENT;
   }
}
```

You need to write a code segment that will use the CustomException class
to immediately return control to the COM caller. You also need to ensure
that the caller has access to the error code. Which code segment should
you use?

1. return Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(CustomException.COR_E_ARGUMENT);
2. return CustomException.COR_E_ARGUMENT;
3. Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(CustomException.COR_E_ARGUMENT);
4. throw new CustomException("Argument is out of bounds"); // correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The COM client code is of course completely agnostic of the .NET Exception type, it only sees the HRESULT error code.  So there is no value-add from adding your own exception types.

All standard .NET Exception derived classes already have a precooked HRESULT value baked-in.  They assign the Exception.HResult property in their constructor.  If you want to generate E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) then use the standard .NET exception class that already uses that error code.  System.ArgumentException.